# Itemize environment within a tabular environment

Tags: tables, itemize

I've got the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
     {Column 1 content}&{\begin{itemize}
         \item Column 2 content
     \end{itemize}}
\end{tabular}
```

But for some reason, the editor I'm using to code - Latexian - keeps giving me errors at lines  3 and 4 of this code, stating

> **LaTeX error: Something's wrong - perhaps a missing \item**
>
> Line 59: \item C

In the PDF preview, the list displays without bullet points, but the table appears properly formatted.

What does this error mean, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't use `itemize` in an `l` column, you need a `p` column.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and I get **Package array Error: Missing arg: token ignored** as well as **Missing # inserted in alignment preamble**. Does it make a difference that I'm using `tabularx`?

Comment: You need `p{3cm}` or some other length.

Comment: @user2615799 You seem to be using some unnecessary curly braces which are not necessary. While extra braces do not harm anybody, at least none that I know off, still we should not get into the habit of using what are not necessary. Please see [the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154577/14103) where I have removed the redundant ones.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are at least two ways of solving your problem.

1. Using a `p`  type column.
2. Using a `minipage` environment.

Which you want to use will depend on the context. But perhaps the later one
might be better when you consider vertical alignments.

---

Here are the solutions and corresponding outputs.

---

Using `p` column.

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{0.4\textwidth}}
  Column 1 content & \begin{itemize}
  \item Column 2 content 1
  \item Column 2 content 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

---

Using a `minipage`.

```
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
  Column 1 content &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Column 2 content 1
    \item Column 2 content 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not your editor that gives you error messages, but latex itself. If it is the whole column that is supposed to be an itemize environment, you can  *simulate* it. Using multirow will let you itemize only some (consecutive) lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|>{\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}l}
   Column 1 content &   Column 2 content \\
   Another column 1 content & Another column 2 content
\end{tabular}\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{r|l}
   Column 1 content &   Column 2 content \\
   Another column 1 content & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}l}
   An itemized list begins here\\ A second item \end{tabular}} \\%
   Still another column 1 content \\
   Final column 1 content  & Final column 2 content
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result:]