# Itemize in tabular // minipage resulting in `Missing \endcsname inserted` error

Tags: tables, errors, itemize, minipage, tabularx

The **`minipage`** solution of this [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154577/27721) is also what I'm looking for, that is,

---

***this one*** :-)

[image]

***not*** this one :-(

[image]

---

The commented-out part of the **MWE** below tries to implement that `minipage` solution, but throws an **`Missing \endcsname inserted`** error.

I doesn't have to be `minipage` for me, as long as it works and is equally simple and elegant :)

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

 \newlength{\mymyrandomlength}

 \settowidth\mymyrandomlength{hello world}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mymyrandomlength}}|*{1}{X}@{}}

ABCDEFG
&

\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\item hello hello goodbye

\strut
\end{itemize}

\\

%\begin{minipage}[t]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item bla bla bla
%\item hello hello goodbye

%\strut
%\end{itemize}
%\end{minipage}
%\\

%\end{tabularx}

\end{tabularx}

% Missing \endcsname inserted.

\end{document}
```

<sub>Cf. also [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13052/spacing-issues-with-itemize-in-a-table) which seems related.</sub>

Comment: Try to remove the new line command \\.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the mandatory argument for `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{3cm}|X@{}}
ABCDEFG &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\item hello hello goodbye\strut
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

In an `X` column you can access the column width by `\hsize`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution -- Use of `\vspace{-xxcm}

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
 \newlength{\mymyrandomlength}
 \settowidth\mymyrandomlength{hello world}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mymyrandomlength}}|*{1}{X}@{}}
ABCDEFG&
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\item hello hello goodbye
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\end{itemize}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```