# Alignment problems with table using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a problem with a table which I am using for a publication. The code is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Summary}
%    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{| c | X | X |}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{| c |>{\centering\arraybackslash}X | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X |}
      \hline
        Reference     & Focus     & Relevance to Model     \\ \hline
        \rule{0pt}{4ex} [4]         & \tabitem Model\newline\tabitem  peformance benchmarks        & Relevant         \\ \hline
         \rule{0pt}{4ex} [5]         & \tabitem Deployment Algorithms \newline \tabitem Analysis of algorithmic efficiency        & Relevant         \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Now this results in the output included in the attached image. I need a center alignment for the heading row, but for the remaining rows, I would like to choose a center alignment for the first column, and a left alignment for the rest. Also, it is evident from the image that the bullets are not aligned properly. I guess this has something to do with the `\tabitem`. I tried replacing it with `itemize` but that just made things worse. So I would really appreciate a workaround to this problem.

[image: generated table]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) - in particular we need to know what definition of `\tabitem` you use.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154570/itemize-environment-within-a-tabular-environment)

Comment: sorry the definition of \tabitem is as follows:  \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

Comment: @Vinod that definition doesn't make a list (which you should be using) it just makes a bullet, so you get the alignment you have specified which is centering (`tabularx` is not relevant to the question you would see the same if you used that markup anywhere in the scope of  `\centering` eg on the main page)

Answer (score 2):

The OP left much undefined by providing snippets of code, rather than an MWE, so I improvised.

I redefined your `\tabitem` to exit vertical mode, and I placed the space following the bullet within the `\llap` itself.  I also made the list raggedright.  I added extra column space before the 2nd column, to offset the `\llap`ed bullet.

Finally, I reduced the `\rule` height from 4ex to 2.5ex to reduce the overhead space in the row entries, and removed the space between the rule and the `[4]`, `[5]` entries, to achieve true horizontal centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\leavevmode\llap{\textbullet~}\raggedright}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Summary}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{| c | @{\hspace{3ex}}X | X |}
      \hline
        Reference     & \hfil Focus\hfil     & \hfil Relevance to Model\hfil     \\ \hline
        \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}[4]         & \tabitem Model\newline\tabitem  peformance benchmarks        & Relevant         \\ \hline
         \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}[5]         & \tabitem Deployment Algorithms \newline \tabitem Analysis of algorithmic efficiency        & Relevant \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the comments, David suggests you use an actual list environment (like `itemize`).  Below, I show how that might be done, though adjustments also have to be made here to allow for the extra space that such environments introduce.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{Summary}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{| c | X | X |}
      \hline
        Reference     & \hfil Focus\hfil     & \hfil Relevance to Model\hfil     \\ \hline
        \rule{0pt}{4ex}[4]         & 
\vspace{-17pt}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}\item Model\item  peformance benchmarks\end{itemize}        
& Relevant         \\ \hline
         \rule{0pt}{4ex}[5]         & 
\vspace{-17pt}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}\item Deployment Algorithms \item Analysis of algorithmic efficiency\end{itemize}
& Relevant \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry about the inadequate code provided due to inexperience....and thank you immensely for the fully working solution....appreciate greatly your time...

Comment: @Vinod Next time try to include a minimum working example that demonstrates the issue.  It not only saves the time of those trying to help you, it often points directly to the actual problem.  It also shows that you are serious about learning something rather than just saying "Can someone please do this for me..."  Welcome to the site.  Many fruitful returns!