# List in tabular environment

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate, multirow

I am trying to insert a list/enumerate(aligned with bullet points) in a tabular environment like this [image]. However, my current code is only able to achieve [image].

My current code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}



\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline

Date & Tuesday 21/01/2020 \\ \hline

Location & Fraser Noble building; Room FN112  \\ \hline

Start time & 10:00  \\ \hline

End time & 12:00  \\ \hline


\multirow{5}{*}{Present} & Samuel Panza (Scribe) \\
          & David Agyeman \\ 
          & Denzil Matthews \\
          & Christopher Hyde \\
          & Nay Htet Hein \\ \hline

Absent with apologies & Ifeanyichukwu Samuel Anene  \\ \hline
Absent without apologies & - \\ \hline
Agenda & Initiation of Development of dry base case \\ \hline

\multirow{5}{*}{Items of Discussion} & Identification of the design specifications of dry stream \\ & base case and the initiation of the development of a \\ & design that separates a  dry stream into a HP gas stream \\ & at 200 bara gas with a maximum cricondenbar of 110 bara, \\ & and an oil stream with a true vapour pressure 0.95 bara at 37.8\si{\celsius} \\ \hline

Actions undertaken & \\ \hline

Next meeting & Thursday 23/01/2020 16:30 - 19:00 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you edit your code so it is compilable.  It should start with a `\documentclass` and end with a `\end{document}`.  See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) for details.

Comment: Hi, I've just done that.

Comment: You want the `p{}` aligning option. For example, start your table with `\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|}` and then you can use `itemize` inside cells, and long text will wrap nicely.

Comment: As an alternative to @rbrignall's suggestion, if the other material should stay as centred columns, you could use `\multicolumn{1}{p{<width>}|}{\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}}`.

Comment: Also this is most likely a duplicate, but I currently don't find the other questions...

Comment: I tried both suggestions and I cannot seem to get it to work

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154570/itemize-environment-within-a-tabular-environment/154577

Comment: Yeah the 2nd link answers my question. Thank you so much. Given that it's a duplicate question, should I delete it?

Comment: I would (delete it).  We can also close it as a duplicate, but it will remain for all posterity to admire (or point and laugh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code: with `enumitem`, I defined a `tabitemize` list, with parameters adapted to a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep = 0pt, before=\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\topsep}, after =\vskip -\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering\sffamily\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{4cm}|X|} \hline
Date & Tuesday 21/01/2020 \\ \hline
Location & Fraser Noble building; Room FN112 \\ \hline
Start time & 10:00 \\ \hline
End time & 12:00 \\ \hline
Present & \begin{tabitemize}
\item Samuel Panza (Scribe)
\item David Agyeman
\item Denzil Matthews
\item Christopher Hyde
\item Nay Htet Hein
\item Bartleby (the Scrivener)
\end{tabitemize} \\ \hline
Absent with apologies & Ifeanyichukwu Samuel Anene \\ \hline
Absent without apologies & -- \\ \hline
Agenda & Initiation of Development of dry base case \\ \hline
Items of Discussion & \begin{tabitemize}
\item Identification of the design specifications of dry stream
base case and the initiation of the development of a
design that separates a dry stream into a HP gas stream
at 200 bara gas with a maximum cricondenbar of 110 bara,
and an oil stream with a true vapour pressure 0.95 bara at \SI[detect-family, math-rm=\mathsf ]{37.8}{\celsius}
\end{tabitemize} \\ \hline
Actions undertaken & \\ \hline
Next meeting & Thursday 23/01/2020 16:30 - 19:00 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is AWESOME!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: should the `Present` be on top or in the centre